# How to use <allow roles="admin"/> with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm having some trouble understanding how to use allow roles in my asp.net website. I have created a SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2017 and have created a table for my users which has a column called `roles` where they will be either a admin, member or sysadmin. In my web.config file I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="admin"/>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

but when I login with a user that doesn't have the role set to admin I am still able to see the page where I should be redirected back to the login page.

Looking online I haven't been able to find a tutorial or explanation on how to do this using a SQL Server database. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: i have added the following code to my root web.config file and now the page seems to just load until a server error appears.

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
</roleManager>
```

error in question:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: I'm not positive, but I still think you need to code that in the login page.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue. If I don't have <roleManager enabled="true"> in the web config then I can load any page without error but to use roles you obviously need to enable it but as soon as I put the previous line of code in the web config I get the SQL error mentioned. Did you find an answer?